# How to install NumPy and Pandas with my current python setup?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, komodo

I am just starting to learn Python in a big hurry (had a positive job interview, was told 'learn Python, NumPy, and Pandas and be ready to take a test on that stuff in 3 weeks'). After my first online Python course, I now have Python 3.8.3 installed along with the Komodo editor.

1. What steps do I take to get NumPy and Pandas installed and going ?
2. Can I do interactive (shell) work with Komodo ?

No time to hack around. Appreciate all help.

Comment: `pip install pandas` and `pip install numpy` would be the easiest and most used way.

Comment: Are you familiar with `komodo` if not better to start with [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/index.html) - `pip install notebook`

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal.

1. Type `pip install numpy` and wait for installation to finish
2. Type `pip install pandas` and wait for installation to finish
3. Head over [here](https://cloudxlab.com/blog/numpy-pandas-introduction/) to get started with using NumPy and Pandas